# Return a data frame from function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have the following code inside a function

```
Myfunc<- function(directory, MyFiles, id = 1:332) {
# uncomment the 3 lines below for testing
#directory<-"local"
#id=c(2, 4)
#MyFiles<-c(f2.csv,f4.csv)
idd<-id

df2 <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:length(idd)) {
  EmptyVector <- read.csv(MyFiles[i])  
  comp_cases[i]<-sum(complete.cases(EmptyVector))
  print(comp_cases[[i]])
  id=idd[i]
  ret2=comp_cases[[i]]
  df2<-rbind(df2,data.frame(id,ret2))
 }
print(df2)
return(df2)
}
```

This works when I try to run it in R by selecting the code inside the function and commenting out the return. I get a nice data frame like from the print statement:

```
> df2
 id ret2
1 2  994
2 4  7112
```

However, when I try to return the dataframe `df2` from the function it only returns the 1st row, ignoring all other values. My problem is that it works within the function for various values I have tried (opening multiple files with various combinations) and not when I try to return the data frame. Can someone help please. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to create a dataframe with the number of complete cases for each `id`. Supposing your files are names with the id-numbers like you specified (e.g. `f2.csv`), you can simplify your function as follows:

```
myfunc <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  y <- vector()
  for(i in 1:length(id)){
    x <- id
    y <- c(y, sum(complete.cases(
      read.csv(as.character(paste0(directory,"/","f",id[i],".csv"))))))
  }
  df <- data.frame(x, y)
  colnames(df) <- c("id","ret2")
  return(df)
}
```

You can call this function like this:

```
myfunc("name-of-your-directory",25:87)
```

---

An explanation of the above code. You have to break down your problem into steps:

1. You need a vector of the id's, that's done by `x <- id`
2. For each `id` you want the number of complete cases. In order to get that, you have to read the file first. That's done by `read.csv(as.character(paste0(directory,"/","f",id[i],".csv")))`. To get the number of complete cases for that file, you have to wrap the `read.csv` code inside `sum` and `complete.cases`.
3. Now you want to add that number to a vector. Therefore you need an empty vector (`y <- vector()`) to which you can add the number of complete cases from step 2. That's done by wrapping the code from step 2 inside `y <- c(y, "code step 2")`. With this you add the number of complete cases for each `id` to the vector `y`.
4. The final step is to combine these two vectors into a dataframe with `df <- data.frame(x, y)` and assign some meaningfull `colnames`.

By including the steps 1, 2 and 3 (except the `y <- vector()` part) in a for-loop, you can iterate over the list of specified id's. Creating the empty vector with `y <- vector()` has to be done before the for-loop, so that the for-loop can add values to `y`.

Comment: @Japp - This worked great. The code is much more cleaner. Yes, I was trying to return a dataframe of complete cases with ID. If you tell me where I was going wrong, it would still help.

Comment: @user3127034 - The main part where you went wrong is by including the `Myfiles` parameter in your function. It wasn't needed as your filenames have all the same structure and can be derived from the id's. I added an explanation. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

This one is actually pretty easy to get around by changing scope.

The issue is that you're creating the initial dataframe as a local variable initially, then you're just swapping out the rows, so you'll wind up with only the first and last results in the dataframe.

When I create a for loop with R and want to add the results of successive queries etc. to some initial dataframe, I do this:

```
function(<some_args>){ 
main_dataframe <<- do something to generate the first set of results from 
whatever you want to iterate, like 1:10, a given list, etc. and create the 
initial dataframe from the first iteration and use the global assignment 
('<<-'), not '<-' or '='

main_dataframe <<- do_something(whatever_you're_iterating_over[1])

for (i in 2:length(whatever_you're_iterating_over)) {
next_dataframe = do_something(whatever_you're_iterating_over[i])

main_dataframe <<- rbind(main_dataframe, next_dataframe)
    }
}
```

The scoping will allow each iteration to create a dataframe that you can append to the original without losing any of the iterations in between the first and the last.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the `<<-` global assignment operator. It was helpful in my context