# Return a dataframe from a function using the input variable as the name of the dataframe

Tags: r, function, return-value

I am trying to write a function to combine a csvs into 1 dataframe based on the name of the csv and then name the dataframe from the pattern that is input into the function. Everything work except returning the dataframe. I can't figure out how to do that using the function input as the name of the dataframe.

I tried what is in this post, but I think the issue is that I only know the name of the dataframe based on the function input: [Return a data frame from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212723/return-a-data-frame-from-function?s=1|3.1010)

```
#### Create files in your current working directory ####
dir <- getwd()

subDir <- 'temp'

dir.create(subDir)

setwd(file.path(dir, subDir))

dir.create('Run1')
dir.create('Run2')

employeeID <- c('123','456','789')
salary <- c(21000, 23400, 26800)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2008-3-25','2007-3-14'))

employeeID <- c('123','456','789')
first <- c('John','Jane','Tom')
last <- c('Doe','Smith','Franks')

data <- data.frame(employeeID,salary,startdate)
name <- data.frame(employeeID,first,last)

write.csv(data, file = "Run1/data.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")
write.csv(name, file = "Run1/name.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")

employeeID <- c('465','798','132')
salary <- c(100000, 500000, 300000)
startdate <- as.Date(c('2000-11-1','2001-3-25','2003-3-14'))

employeeID <- c('465','798','132')
first <- c('Jay','Susan','Tina')
last <- c('Jones','Smith','Thompson')

data <- data.frame(employeeID,salary,startdate)
name <- data.frame(employeeID,first,last)

write.csv(data, file = "Run2/data.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")
write.csv(name, file = "Run2/name.csv",row.names=FALSE, na="")

#### function #### 
files_to_df <- function(pattern){ 

  # pattern <- "data"
  filenames <- list.files(recursive = TRUE, pattern = pattern) 

  df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)

  # Name each dataframe with the run and filename
  names(df_list) <- str_sub(list, 1, 4)

  # Create combined dataframe  
  df <- df_list %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'run')

  # Assign dataframe to the name of the pattern  
  assign(pattern, df)

  # Return the dataframe  
  return(data.frame(pattern))
  #list2env(pattern,.GlobalEnv)
}

#### Run function ####
files_to_df(c("data"))
```

Comment: You are not assignning the return value. `data <- files_to_df(c("data"))`.

Comment: It's de be more clean to have your `data.frames` in a cleaned named list rather than free in your workspace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made two changes of your code:

1.) `str_sub(list, 1, 4)` -> `str_sub(filenames, 1, 4)`
list is a function and dont contain any content.

2.) `return(data.frame(pattern))` -> `return(df)`
returning the data.frame and not a sting.

```
files_to_df <- function(pattern){ 

  # pattern <- "data"
  filenames <- list.files(recursive = TRUE, pattern = pattern) 

  df_list <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, header = TRUE)

  # Name each dataframe with the run and filename
  names(df_list) <- str_sub(filenames, 1, 4)

  # Create combined dataframe  
  df <- df_list %>%
    bind_rows(.id = 'run')

  # Assign dataframe to the name of the pattern  
  assign(pattern, df)

  # Return the dataframe  
  return(data.frame(df))
  #list2env(pattern,.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Comment: @Erin It is a good practice to mark the question solved, and upvoted the answer if it was useful (;